# Security deposit

Tags: rental-property

My landlord sold my house to a 3rd party.  We moved after closing. Does the landlord have to refund the security deposit in full since he no longer owned the property when we moved?

Answer (score 3):

The security deposit goes with the lease, so he will transfer the deposit to the new owner, who will return it to you when the time comes. Unless, in your state, security deposits are put in escrow accounts, and again you will get it back at the end of the lease..